# Copy sharepoint list items across different farms

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I am trying to copy items to a list but it sits on a different farm in the same domain. Please point me in the right direction. Some of the code is as below:

```
string _destination = null;
        string _url = null;

            string FieldID = sourceItem["Field 1"].ToString();
            string EmpInitials = "";

            foreach (SPListItem itemL in listItems)
            {
                if (itemL["Destination List"].ToString().ToLower() == _employer.ToLower())
                {
                    _url = itemL["Site Url"].ToString();
                }
            }

            using (SPSite DestinationSite = new SPSite(_url)) 
            {
                SPWeb DestinationWeb = DestinationSite.OpenWeb();
                SPList DestinationList = DestinationWeb.Lists.TryGetList(Destination);

                if (DestinationList != null)
                {
                    SPListItemCollection dListItems = DestinationList.Items;
                    SPListItem newItem = dListItems.Add();
                    newItem["Field 1"] = ClaimNumber;
                    newItem.Update();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do you know what part of your code that does not work?

Comment: The code works fine if the site is on the same web application but if it is on another farm I get the error :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://sitename/lists/dest could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

Comment: You could try accessing the list on the other farm by using WCF Data Services. Please refer to the following link
[Accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists by Using WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You are using server side API. It can only be executed on a SharePoint Server and can only access current farm.

If you want to access sites in another farm you need to use CSOM or web services.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion:

SharePoint 2013: PowerShell to copy or update list items across SharePoint sites and farms

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25125.sharepoint-2013-powershell-to-copy-or-update-list-items-across-sharepoint-sites-and-farms.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

I believe it supports 2010 to 2013, 2010 to 2010, and 2013 to 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't tickle your fancy you can try it via web services:

**How to: Update List Items**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx

**Lists.UpdateListItems Method**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx

I used the snippets from the above links to add the process to a WCF service that was on the same WFE as the remote sharepoint server (different domain too) and made a call to that web service from a web part that was on the local sharepoint server. This allowed me to insert or update list items on both servers.